# Ordenar a visualização das imagens para que as horizontais apareçam primeiro que as verticais

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de imagens onde elas deveriam ser cortadas da seguinte forma:

```
...
list($imagem,$extensao) = explode(".",$nc->Fotos);
$foto = $imagem.'_1.'.$extensao;
$arquivo = '../../fotos/albuns/'.$nc->NomeAlbum.'/'.$foto;
if(!file_exists($arquivo))
{
list($ft,$extensao) = explode('_1.',$foto);
$foto = $ft.'.'.$extensao;
$this->visualizarImagemCortada($foto);
}
...
```

E o método que era para cortar:

```
/**
 * Método corta a foto
 * Encontra-se na página visualizar-fotos.php
 * @access public
 * @param string $album
 * @return $visualizar
 */
public function visualizarImagemCortada($album){
  $sqlImagens = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM nc_fotos WHERE IdFotos = '".$album."';");
  while($nc = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlImagens))
    {
      $imagem = '../../site-novo/fotos/albuns/'.$nc->NomeAlbum.'/'.$nc->Fotos;
      list($img,$extensao) = explode(".",$nc->Fotos);
      if($extensao == 'jpg')
      {
        $filename = $imagem;
        list($imagem,$extensao) = explode(".",$nc->Fotos);
        $foto = $imagem.'_1.'.$extensao;
        $newFilename = $foto;
        $left = 50;
        $top = 50;
        $cropWidth = 300;
        $cropHeight = 300;
        $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($cropWidth,$cropHeight);
        $currentImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopy($canvas,$currentImage,0,0,$left,$top,$cropWidth,$cropHeight);
        imagejpeg($canvas,$newFilename,100);

      /*  
      $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagem);
      // $size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
      //$im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 50, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
      $im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 50, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 300, 'height' => 300]);
      if ($im2 !== FALSE) 
      {
        list($imagem,$extensao) = explode(".",$nc->Fotos);
        imagejpeg($im2, '../../site-novo/fotos/albuns/'.$nc->NomeAlbum.'/'.$imagem.'_1.'.$extensao);
      }
      */
      }
      if($extensao == 'png')
      {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($imagem);
        $size = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
        $im2 = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 50, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
        if ($im2 !== FALSE) 
        {
          list($imagem,$extensao) = explode(".",$nc->Fotos);
          imagepng($im2, '../../site-novo/fotos/albuns/'.$nc->NomeAlbum.'/'.$imagem.'_1.'.$extensao);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Do qual minhas 02 tentativas na condicional `if($extensao == 'jpg')` por alguma razão não funcionaram e com isso as imagens foram convertidas em thumbnail, mas não recortadas como deveriam, ficando a maior bagunça na visualização e as imagens verticais e horizontais ficam misturadas estragando assim o layout.

Minha tentativa de resolver isso foi:

```
$imageSize = getimagesize($foto);
$width = $imageSize[0];
$height = $imageSize[1];
if($width > $height)
{
  $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-3"><img src="'.$foto.'" class="img- 
  thumbnail"></div>';  
}
else
{
  $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-3"><img src="'.$foto.'" class="img- 
  thumbnail"></div>';  
}
```

Mas não funcionou! Como faço para que as imagens horizontais apareçam primeiro que as verticais?

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar cada imagem numa div com tamanho definido e ajustar elas dentro da sua div, mesmo sendo horizontal ou vertical? Assim vai ficar tudo organizado.

Comment: Olá Sam. Perdão. Não consegui entender.

Comment: Veja o print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAYZJ.png ... cada imagem centralizada dentro de divs com o mesmo tamanho

Comment: Há outra forma também de organizar, ficando cada imagem lado a lado, sem precisar usar div.

Comment: Oi Sam. Tem como me mostrar um exemplo? Pois estou levando uma surra aqui para ajustar isso, já que as imagens verticais ficam no meio das horizontais e vice-versa, então já viu como está o álbum.  rs rs rs

Comment: Tem como mostrar um print de como ficou bagunçado só pra eu ter uma ideia?

Comment: Certo. Editei o post e coloquei um print.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93728/discussion-between-sam-and-fox-11).

Comment: olá Sam. Perdoe-me a demora, pois o dia hoje foi super corrido. Consegui resolver instalando a biblioteca WideImage. Obrigado.